# Bought iOS app template that is playing white noise when it shouldn't?

Tags: ios, xcode, templates

I bought an iOS app template recently. I am working my way through changing it (not code just graphics). When I load it onto my test device or emulator, it starts playing white noise? 
I am a bit of a noob, I don't code very well and pretty much use simple UI to change app templates.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Comment: Can you give us a bit more info about the app template? Is it ObjC or Swift or other?

Comment: Its in ObjC. What other info could i post?